# Decompressing large streams with Python tarfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, tarfile

I have a large `.tar.xz` file that I am downloading with python requests that needs to be decompressed before writing to the disk (Due to limited disk space). I have a solution which works for smaller files, but larger files hang indefinitely.

```
import io
import requests
import tarfile
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, stream=True)

compressed_data = io.BytesIO(response.content)
tar = tarfile.open(mode='r|*' ,fileobj=compressed_data, bufsize=16384)
tar.extractall(path='/path/')
```

It hangs at `io.BytesIO` for larger files.

Is there a way to pass the stream to `fileobj` without reading the entire stream? or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: How large is "large"? That would be useful information if we want to try reproducing this behavior.

Comment: At least 8GB. It may fail with smaller, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Creating a BytesIO object means you're storing everything in RAM -- defeats the point of streaming.

Comment: @Spiff  I think that's due to the fact the `tarfile.open` sends all the extracted archive to sdtout... and this is the cause of "larger files hang indefinitely" (in reality after a "while" it will start). If you temporary turn it off you will get a great improvement (see my answer for details)

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize the `lzma` library to decompress `.xz` files. Download large files in chunks (to be memory efficient) and decompress them, then write to disk. Here's a script that I use on my server to download large `tar.xz` once a week, the file sizes are typically around 6GB. This should work for you too.

```
import requests
import lzma
import tarfile
import os
import tempfile

url = 'your tar.xz url'

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()

    # Initialize LZMA decompressor
    decompressor = lzma.LZMADecompressor()

    # Create a temporary file to store the decompressed data
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=32 * 1024):
            data = decompressor.decompress(chunk)
            tmp_file.write(data)

        # Get the name of the temporary file
        tmp_file_name = tmp_file.name

# Now extract from the temporary file
with tarfile.open(tmp_file_name, mode="r") as tar:
    tar.extractall(path="/home/arrafi/")

# Clean up the temporary file
os.remove(tmp_file_name)
```

`chunk_size=32 * 1024` modify the chunk size according to your specs.

Now, if you insist on using `io`, modify your code according to download and decompress in chunks. Your code hangs because it is trying to download all at once, hence running out of memory. To download large files, the file have to be downloaded in chunks to be memory efficient.

Comment: is the `if chunk:` really needed? What does it check?

Comment: yeah, you're right that's not needed. damn! though I never really noticed that

Comment: another thing: [`decompress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html#lzma.LZMADecompressor.decompress) should take `byte-array` object, but [`response.iter_content`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) "will automatically decode the gzip and deflate transfer-encodings", for "a raw stream of bytes" you should use `Response.raw. Response.iter_content`. I haven't tested them, both works with your experience?

Comment: I will give that a try and see how it works next week

Comment: ahaha! Perfect, I will wait for the feedback:)

Comment: I've been using this script for quite some time now on my server, never got an exception

Comment: Thanks @MusabbirArrafi for the answer, though this doesn't quite work for my use case. The reason I need to decompress without writing to disk is because I have limited space. This solution works but would need double the space of the size of the uncompressed file to work.

Comment: sorry, my solution is based on your memory issue. your program hangs because it runs out of memory for large files.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`response.iter_content`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) to stream a `tar.xz`-download into chunks which will be incrementally decompress **in-memory** by [`LZMADecompressor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html#lzma.LZMADecompressor) and passed to a buffer. Once the downloaded is terminated the `tar`-archive contained in the buffer will be [extracted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open).

```
from io import BytesIO
from lzma import LZMADecompressor, FORMAT_XZ
import tarfile
import requests
import contextlib


url = '' #                                 url of the data
chunk_size = 2**14 #                       just an example
path_tar_archive_dir = 'downloaded_tar' #  location of the extraction of the archive


with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(url, stream=True)

    # create buffer to store streaned data
    with BytesIO() as bw:
        # xz-decompressor
        d = LZMADecompressor(format=FORMAT_XZ) # also without arguments

        # read incoming data
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            # in-memory automatic incremental decompression
            data = d.decompress(chunk)
            if data:
                bw.write(data)
            
        if not d.eof:
            raise Exception('EOF of streaming data not reached')
        
        print('[OK] Download and xz-decompression of stream data')
        # set stream position at the start
        bw.seek(0)
        
        # temporary shutdown tar-stdout
        f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):

            # extract the archieve from the buffer
            with tarfile.open(fileobj=bw, mode='r') as tar:
                # extract the archieve at the given directory
                tar.extractall(path_tar_archieve_dir, None, numeric_owner=False)
            
        print('[OK] Extraction tar-archieve')
```

Notice that the signature of [`tar.extractall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#extraction-filters) will support a new keyword-only parameter, `filter`, from Python 3.9.17.

NOTE on performance:
`tar` send all its output to `stdout` and by redirecting it to `devnull` the performance of the extraction will dramatically increase!

---

I set up a `Flask` server to test the code on *localhost*. I use a 34 MB tar.xz-archive and it took a while to fully download it. Without the performance trick it will take lot of RAM, in my case up to 200 MB. Instead with redirection to `devnull` it's execution will be even difficult to notice in terms of time and RAM.

Here my test `server.py` (just for localhost tests!)

```
"""
# start the server
$ flask --app server run --debug
"""
from flask import Flask
from flask import send_from_directory
import os


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/archive/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def archive():
    # create route http://127.0.0.1:5000/archive/
    
    abs_path_to_archive = # <- here add the path!
    dir_path, basename = os.path.split(abs_path_to_archive)

    return send_from_directory(dir_path, basename, as_attachment=False)
```

Then start the server in ins own terminal

```bash
$ flask --app server run --debug
```

and run the above program to download the archive using in another terminal with `url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/archive/"`.